# Android inter-component process relations

Tags: android, process, android-activity, package, relation

lets say I have two applications(manifests). Then , both of those have a different name.

Now, suppose there is Activity A ,B,C in com.packageOne application.
ANd suppose there is Activity X,Y,Z in com.packageTwo application.

Question:

Can I somehow use some combination of android:process shared userid etc in order to get Activity A from packageOne, to run in address space of com.packageTwo. But I dont want B,C to run in the same process space as Activity A. (Assume signing with same keys, and signing with different keys, my guess is former is possible but not the later).

Similarly, can I have Activity A and Activity X run in some process of their own, s.t.

BC runs in process of packageOne
YZ runs in process of packageTwo

AX runs in some new process.

Ty

Comment: I don't think that's possible due to security, as you could fiddle with permissions etc. One package is really all you need for 99% of tasks.

Comment: The aim is related to security verification hence I am asking this question. I am also hoping this is not possible, but just curious if anyone has done anything of this sort before ....

Answer (score 0):

For activities you have tag `android:process` that you can use to launch your A activity in the com.packageTwo process. But I've never tried this approach :)